# Toggling same class names except for one (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, toggle, state, editing

I am trying to prevent a paragraph element with a class attribute of 'show' from toggling away on the click event on **updateButton**. I've tried if else statements but to no avail.

I'm essentially **trying to create an editing state when I click update button** and all the text on the bottom of these buttons need to show (the paragraph elements). Though there is one button with text underneath it already which I want to prevent from toggling the class .hide.

The other buttons already have the **.hide** class attribute on them already so when toggled from the click event, they appear.

**TLDR:** I want to prevent the one paragraph element with no **.hide** class attribute from toggling it on when I toggle all the other paragraph elements in the **.risk-text** container.

```js
// select indicator div
const riskIndicator = document.getElementById("Risk__indicator");
// select update button
const updateButton = document.getElementById("Update_button");
// Indicator buttons
const indicatorButton = document.getElementsByClassName("Risk_indicator_button");
// Indicator 'check every..' text
const checkIndicatorText = document.querySelectorAll(".risk-text");


    // select update button
        updateChange: updateButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            riskIndicator.classList.toggle("active");
        });

    // If statement to check whether the Risk Indicator is active to apply background changes
        editState: updateButton.addEventListener("click", function(el) {
                [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.risk-text'), function(el) {
                    // loop through text indicator elements checking to see if it's got a hidden class attribute
                    el.classList.toggle('hide');
                });
        });
```

Comment: share html code

Comment: The HTML
https://jsfiddle.net/gxhsz8ky

Images of it
http://imgur.com/a/Q8oye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case:

If you want to exclude it only once, and then toggle this element with others, do something like:

```
   editState: updateButton.addEventListener("click", function(el) {
            [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.risk-text:not(.hide)'), function(el) {
                // loop through text indicator elements checking to see if it's got a hidden class attribute
                el.classList.toggle('hide');
            });
    });
```

If you want to leave the "ember" element alone, then

```
   editState: updateButton.addEventListener("click", function(el) {
            [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.risk-text:not(.low_risk_text__wrap--risk-middle-amber)'), function(el) {
                // loop through text indicator elements checking to see if it's got a hidden class attribute
                el.classList.toggle('hide');
            });
    });
```

You can also add new class, like "spareMe", and exclude it with .not()

Comment: Thank you so much Michal, the first one did the trick for what I was looking to do! It now successfully prevents the middle paragraph element from toggling the hide class attribute! I had a .show class attribute on there for the ones I don't want to change so I amended to look like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/mcLouxr4/1/